# Using a JButton to stop Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sorting, japplet

I have an applet that sorts arrays. On one `JPanel` it sorts though one array using a sort that is chosen by the user, and on another `JPanel` it uses all four at the same time, each in their thread.

Code for the 4 at the same time.

```
private class startAH implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        allArrays.clear();
        bubble.clear();
        selection.clear();
        quick.clear();
        merge.clear();

        startBut.setEnabled(false);
        threadStart = true;

        loopJump = (int) spinner.getValue();
        loopFinish = loopJump*10;

        currentPercentBubble =0;
        currentPercentSelection =0;
        currentPercentMerge =0;
        currentPercentQuick =0;

        bubbleBool=false;
        selectionBool=false;
        quickBool=false;
        mergeBool=false;
        saveBut.setEnabled(false);

        iBubble=0;
        iSelection=0;
        iQuick=0;
        iMerge=0;

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int outLoop = loopJump; outLoop <= loopFinish; outLoop+=loopJump)
                {

                    Long elapsedTime=(long) 0;
                    Long currentTime;



                    for(int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 10; innerLoop++){

                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        try {
                            int[] intArray = new int[outLoop];
                            sort.fillArray(intArray);
                            sort.bubbleSort(intArray);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        currentTime = endTime-startTime;
                        elapsedTime +=currentTime;
                        currentPercentBubble++;
                        repaint();
                    }

                    long finalTime = (long) (elapsedTime/10);

                    String[] current = new String[2];
                    current[0]=""+outLoop;
                    current[1]=""+finalTime;
                    bubble.add(iBubble, current);

                    iBubble++;

                }
                allArrays.add(3, bubble);
                bubbleBool = true;
                saveCheck();
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int outLoop = loopJump; outLoop <= loopFinish; outLoop+=loopJump)
                {

                    Long elapsedTime=(long) 0;
                    Long currentTime;

                    for(int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 10; innerLoop++){
                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        try {
                            int[] intArray = new int[outLoop];
                            sort.fillArray(intArray);
                            sort.selectionSort(intArray);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }
                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        currentTime = endTime-startTime;
                        elapsedTime +=currentTime;
                        currentPercentSelection++;
                        repaint();

                    }

                    long finalTime = (long) (elapsedTime/10);

                    String[] current = new String[2];
                    current[0]=""+outLoop;
                    current[1]=""+finalTime;
                    selection.add(iSelection, current);

                    iSelection++;

                }
                allArrays.add(2, selection);
                selectionBool = true;
                saveCheck();
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int outLoop = loopJump; outLoop <= loopFinish; outLoop+=loopJump)
                {

                    Long elapsedTime=(long) 0;
                    Long currentTime;



                    for(int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 10; innerLoop++){

                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        try {
                            int[] intArray = new int[outLoop];
                            sort.fillArray(intArray);
                            sort.quickSort(intArray);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }
                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        currentTime = endTime-startTime;
                        elapsedTime +=currentTime;
                        currentPercentMerge++;
                        repaint();
                    }

                    long finalTime = (long) (elapsedTime/10);

                    String[] current = new String[2];
                    current[0]=""+outLoop;
                    current[1]=""+finalTime;
                    quick.add(iQuick, current);

                    iQuick++;

                }
                allArrays.add(0, quick);
                quickBool = true;
                saveCheck();
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int outLoop = loopJump; outLoop <= loopFinish; outLoop+=loopJump)
                {

                    Long elapsedTime=(long) 0;
                    Long currentTime;



                    for(int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < 10; innerLoop++){

                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        try {
                            int[] intArray = new int[outLoop];
                            sort.fillArray(intArray);
                            sort.mergeSort(intArray);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        currentTime = endTime-startTime;
                        elapsedTime +=currentTime;
                        currentPercentQuick++;
                        repaint();
                    }

                    long finalTime = (long) (elapsedTime/10);

                    String[] current = new String[2];
                    current[0]=""+outLoop;
                    current[1]=""+finalTime;
                    merge.add(iMerge, current);

                    iMerge++;

                }
                allArrays.add(1, merge);
                mergeBool = true;
                saveCheck();
                repaint();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Code for the single:

```
private class startAH implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                singleSortStart = true;
                currentPercent = 0;
                startBut.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                    selectedSort = (String)listBox.getSelectedItem();
                    selectSort((String)listBox.getSelectedItem(), numbersForSort);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                saveBut.setEnabled(true);
                startBut.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

They use the sorts from another class, I want to be able to allow the user to be able to stop them while running without making them use different sorting methods. Any ideas?

Code for the sorts:

```
public class Sorts {
static Random arrayFill = new Random();
static final int GREATESTNUMBER = 100;

public void fillArray(int[] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = arrayFill.nextInt(GREATESTNUMBER);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param array
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void bubbleSort(int[] array) throws InterruptedException {

    int n = array.length;

    for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int k = i + 1;
            if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                swap(i, k, array);
            }

        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param i
 * @param j
 * @param array
 */
private void swap(int i, int j, int[] array) {

    int temp;
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param array
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void selectionSort(int[] array) throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
    {
        int index = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
            if (array[j] < array[index])
                index = j;

        int smallerNumber = array[index]; 
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = smallerNumber;

        //delayThread();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param a
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void mergeSort(int[ ] a) throws InterruptedException
{
    int[] tmp = new int[a.length];
    mergeSort(a, tmp,  0,  a.length - 1);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param tmp
 * @param left
 * @param right
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
private void mergeSort(int[ ] a, int[ ] tmp, int left, int right) throws InterruptedException
{
    if( left < right )
    {
        int center = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, tmp, left, center);
        mergeSort(a, tmp, center + 1, right);
        merge(a, tmp, left, center + 1, right);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param a
 * @param tmp
 * @param left
 * @param right
 * @param rightEnd
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
private void merge(int[ ] a, int[ ] tmp, int left, int right, int rightEnd )throws InterruptedException
{
    int leftEnd = right - 1;
    int k = left;
    int num = rightEnd - left + 1;

    while(left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd)
        if(a[left]<=a[right])
            tmp[k++] = a[left++];
        else
            tmp[k++] = a[right++];

    while(left <= leftEnd)    // Copy rest of first half
        tmp[k++] = a[left++];

    while(right <= rightEnd)  // Copy rest of right half
        tmp[k++] = a[right++];

    // Copy tmp back
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++, rightEnd--){
        a[rightEnd] = tmp[rightEnd];
        //delayThread();
    }

}

/**
 * 
 * @param array
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void quickSort(int array[]) throws InterruptedException 
// pre: array is full, all elements are non-null integers
// post: the array is sorted in ascending order
{
    quickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);// quicksort all the elements in the array
}

/**
 * 
 * @param array
 * @param start
 * @param end
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high) throws InterruptedException {

    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
        return;

    if (low >= high)
        return;

    //pick the pivot
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    int pivot = arr[middle];

    //make left < pivot and right > pivot
    int i = low, j = high;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

        while (arr[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i <= j) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    //recursively sort two sub parts
    if (low < j)
        quickSort(arr, low, j);

    if (high > i)
        quickSort(arr, i, high);
}
}
```

I have another JPanel that uses different sorts with a delay so I can show the array being sorted, and I can stop the thread with this

```
private void delayThread() throws InterruptedException
{
    repaint();
    Thread.sleep(slider.getValue());

    if(stopThread){
        startBut.setEnabled(true);
        stopBut.setEnabled(false);  
        stopThread = false;
        listBox.setEnabled(true);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

and each sort has the delay

```
private void bubbleSortD(int[] array) throws InterruptedException 
{
    int n = array.length;

    for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            int k = i + 1;
            if (array[i] > array[k]) {
                swapD(i, k, array);

            }
            delayThread();
        }

    }
}
```

but I can't find a way to do this with out get the single and the 4 to use different sorts like this one does, and I don't want to write the sorts 3 times, if anyone has a way to get it to 1, that would be amazing.
they are all in different class by the way.

Comment: What have you attempted? I don't see code relating to stopping a thread

Comment: If you create anonymous Threads you cant stop it.

Comment: @MuratK Not true; you could still stop it by requiring a boolean to be true for it to continue, then setting that boolean to false, allowing the thread to die gracefully (which is actually the [practiced way of terminating threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html))

Comment: I haven't attempted it, I did but deleted the code. I have stopped an anonymous Thread, not a very clean way but I couldn't think of another way. (Added it to the end of the question)

Comment: If you don't show an attempt, people will suspect you haven't put any effort into finding out how to do so (which is a requirement for questions; show effort). The way you're doing it (using a `stopThread` boolean) is actually the *correct* way of terminating a thread (read the link in my comment; scroll down to "What do I do")

Comment: @VinceEmigh If I was to use the same method to stop the single and 4, would i put the delayThread method in the sorts or in each of the JPanels? This is the part that I don't understand.

Comment: You would put it within the `Runnable` of those threads, **not** within your actionPerformed method. The boolean needs to be `volatile` as well, or else only the thread which changes the boolean will see the changes right away. Volatile ensures ALL threads see the updated variable as soon as it has been updated

Comment: Thank you! really helped I have sorted it now